# Two Register Forms in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

Is it possible to have 2 additional user creation forms including the one that comes from Laravel.

1 form: 
Users

> User ID Name Email  Password

2 form: 
Employees

> User ID Name Email  Password and few more additional fields

3 form: 
Residents

> User ID Name Email  Password and few more additional fields

I hope the above question makes sense, additional clarification: I'd like to join Users Table with employees and resident, just these 4 fields - UserID, name, email and password from Users Table the rest from Employees Table or Resident Table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you need to specify the relationship in the models.

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}

class Resident extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'residents';

    public function resident()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps those relationships should be named 'user'?